# Determine if circle contain point ( geographic ) while the number before the point are equals

Tags: geometry, circles

I want to check if circle contain some point(latitude and longitude). the problem I have is that the number before the point are equals, for example:

1. $\left(x-22.276706726696727\right)^2+\left(y-70.77873229980467\right)^2=4.51^2$
2. $\left(x-22.348170603696186\right)^2+\left(y-70.95245361328125\right)^2=5.47^2$

I insert the equations into desmos and this is the result:
[image]

If I will insert show it on some map space it will be:
[image]

There is way to check it more precisely and maybe my problem is that I dont normalize it? any suggestions?
 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your map of Gujarat, it seems that you are using degrees on the left hand side for the circle centres (co-ordinates in Rajkot and perhaps near Kuvadava) but something like kilometres on the right hand side.

Hence the confusion with your almost concentric circles, which assume the units are the same on each side.

Comment: the radius is given in meters, so I divide it by 1000, but its doesnt matter it still the same when I draw it.

Comment: I think I  need to convert the degrees to km.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by converting the degress to UTM, if you are facing with this problem you can check this:
[Degress Convert to UTM](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/utmformulas.htm)

In addition if you are facing the problem on the programming side you can check this lib for example in PHP :
[gPoint](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/10671.html)